# Database creation command in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

In my project I want to create console commands for dropping and creating DB, just like in [Symfony2 like database creation command in laravel console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27813801/symfony2-like-database-creation-command-in-laravel-console) The way described in the answer to that question works fine for dropping DB, but when I try to create it with this code:

```
$dbType = \Config::get('database.default');
$dbName = \Config::get('database.connections')[$dbType]['database'];
\DB::statement("CREATE DATABASE `$dbName`");
```

I get an exception: `SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database 'my_awesome_db_name'`. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Laravel is trying to connect to MySQL and select the database `my_awesome_db_name`. This isn't possible, because that database name doesn't exist yet (you haven't created it), so MySQL fails on the internal `USE my_awesome_db_name` command.

Comment: yep. And is there any way to avoid this issue in Laravel?

Comment: My best guess is to leave the 'database' config option blank in `config/database.php`, and then call `DB::setDatabaseName('my_awesome_db_name');` after you've created the database.

Comment: Have a look through the [Laravel database class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php) to see how it works.

Comment: it's a bit tricky, but it seems that there is no other options :( It would be cool if Eloquent tried to reconnect without db_name parameter in case DB with such name isn't found.